# How can I do a Union all in Entity Framework LINQ To Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, entity-framework-4, union-all

I came across a scenario where I had to use Union all, how can I achieve so in LINQ to entities ?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

[Here is the answer you are looking for](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqtosql/thread/17212688-37bb-48dd-b7d6-defedba1737f). Use the [Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) keyword.

From the example:

```
var query = (from x in db.Table1 select new {A = x.A, B = x.B})
    .Concat( from y in db.Table2 select new {A = y.A, B = y.B} );
```

Comment: This is great. I mistakenly used query1.Union(query2). Seems logical, right?

Answer (score 8):

I believe `Concat` is what you're looking for.

```
var allResults = resultSet1.Concat(resultSet2);
```

Obviously, both result sets must use the same type. And I believe there my be other requirements about how the result sets are constructed in the first place, but I don't know all the details.