# Union in linq entity framework

Tags: .net, entity

I want to perform the following work in entity framework that can be done in sql very easily.

```
select 0 as employeeid, 'Select' as employeeName 
union

Select employeeid, employeeName from tblemployee where IsActive=true
```

help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do a Union all in Entity Framework LINQ To Entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9828308/how-can-i-do-a-union-all-in-entity-framework-linq-to-entities)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

With `UNION`

```
var t= Enumerable
         .Range(0,1)
         .Select (e =>
                    new{employeeid=0,employeeName="Select"})
       .Union(
          db.tblemployee
          .Select (u =>
                   new {employeeid=u.employeeid,employeeName=u.employeeName} ));
```

With `UNION ALL`

```
var t= Enumerable
         .Range(0,1)
         .Select (e =>
                    new{employeeid=0,employeeName="Select"})
       .Concat(
          db.tblemployee
          .Select (u =>
                   new {employeeid=u.employeeid,employeeName=u.employeeName} ));
```

Where db is the data context

Comment: Can you please explain why start with "Enumerable.Range(0,1)"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `tblemployee` is being mapped to an entity named `Employee` and your `DbContext` has a collection of `Employee`s named `Employees`, you can do the following:

```
var allEmployeesPlusAnEmptyOne = 
    new[] { new Employee { EmployeeId = 0, Name = "Select" } }
    .Concat(dbContext.Employees.Where(e => e.IsActive));
```

...as mentioned by @Arion, you can use `Union()` if you want the Entity framework to remove duplicate objects, although I assume there wouldn't be any.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Your code is working nicely.