# Entity Framework: How to query a number of related tables in a database making a single trip

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have a query that is currently far too slow.
I am trying to search a Code (a string) on the main page that will bring the user the relevant info. 
Eg. The user can search a code from the main page and this will search for the code in Job, Work Phase, Wbs, Work Element, EA, Jobcard and Estimate and return the relevant info. 
I make a number of trips to the database to collect the data i need when I believe it can be done in just one. 
I have a number of tables that are all linked:
Contracts, Jobs, WorkPhases, Wbss, Engineering Activities, Jobcards and Estimates.
Contracts have a list of Jobs,
Jobs have a list of Workphases,
Workphases have a list of Wbss etc

Is there a quicker way to do this?

```cs
public Result Handle(Query query)
{                   
    query.Code = query.Code ?? string.Empty;

    var result = new Result();

    //result.SetParametersFromPagedQuery(query);
    result.Items = new List<Item>();

    if (query.SearchPerformed)
    {
        var contracts = _db.Contracts.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(contracts.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.Contract,
            ContractName = x.Name,
            Url = string.Format("Admin/Contract/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();


        var jobs = _db.Jobs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(jobs.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            ContractName = x.Contract.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.Job,
            Url = string.Format("Admin/Job/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();

        //var workPhases = _db.WorkPhases.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ContractPhase.Code.ToLower() == query.Code.ToLower());
        var workPhases = _db.WorkPhases.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ContractPhase.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(workPhases.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.ContractPhase.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.ContractPhase.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.WorkPhase,
            Url = string.Format("Admin/WorkPhase/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();

        var wbss = _db.WBSs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(wbss.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.WBS,
            Url = string.Format("Admin/WBS/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();

        var eas = _db.EngineeringActivities.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(eas.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.EA,
            Url = string.Format("Admin/EngineeringActivity/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();

        var jcs = _db.Jobcards.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(jcs.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.EA,
            Url = string.Format("Admin/JobCard/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();

        var estimates = _db.Estimates.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code);

        result.Items = result.Items.Concat(estimates.Select(x => new Item()
        {
            Code = x.Code,
            Id = x.Id,
            Name = x.Name,
            Type = MainPageSearchEnum.Estimate,
            Url = string.Format("Estimation/Estimate/Edit/{0}", x.Id)
        })).ToList();

    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there most certainly is a way to query multiple tables. You can use the `Include()` method extension for your query. for instance:

```
var examplelist = _db.Contracts.(v => v.id == "someid" && v.name == "anotherfilter").Include("theOtherTablesName").ToList();
```

You can include as many tables as you like this way. This is the recommended method.

You can also use the `UnionAll()` method but you'd have to define your queries separately for this

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

This library has a Query Future feature which allows batching multiple queries in a single roundtrip.

Example:

```
// using Z.EntityFramework.Plus; // Don't forget to include this.
var ctx = new EntitiesContext();

// CREATE a pending list of future queries
var futureCountries = ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();
var futureStates = ctx.States.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();

// TRIGGER all pending queries in one database round trip
// SELECT * FROM Country WHERE IsActive = true;
// SELECT * FROM State WHERE IsActive = true
var countries = futureCountries.ToList();

// futureStates is already resolved and contains the result
var states = futureStates.ToList();
```

Wiki: [EF+ Query Future](http://entityframework-plus.net/query-future)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb155162%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) / [UnionAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335484(v=vs.110).aspx) operator?

It's purpose is exactly like you wish - combine the identical data from different sources.

Furthermore due to the concept of [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution) your query will only be executed when you actually iterate over the result (or call a method that does that, for example - `.ToList()`

```
var contractsQuery = _db.Contracts.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code).Select(x=>new {Code=x.Code, Id=x.Id, ...});
var jobsQuery = _db.Jobs.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Code == query.Code).Select(x=>new{Code=x.Code, Id=x.Id, ...});
var workPhasesQuery = _db.WorkPhases.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.ContractPhase.Code == query.Code).Select(x=>new{Code=x.Code, Id=x.Id, ...});
    // and so on
var combinedQuery = contractsQuery.UnionAll(jobsQuery).UnionAll(workPhasesQuery ).UnionAll(...
var result = combinedQuery.ToList();
```

A similar question is [Union in linq entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328416/union-in-linq-entity-framework)
Another code sample can be found [here](http://www.codelocker.net/30501/create-union-query-with-entity-framework/)

Please notice that this is exactly the same concept of manipulating data as in T-SQL [union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql), and under the covers you will get an sql query using a `union` operator

Comment: Hi ironstone13, thank you for your response. I am new to this area. But would this not be as slow as I still have to query each table one at at time?

Comment: @user3597791, well, with this you actually run the query only in the line `var result = combinedQuery.ToList()` - read about the concept of *deferred execution* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution

Comment: @user3597791, you're welcome!
By the way you can verify what queries are being executed using Sql Server profiler, or EF query logging https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @user3597791, obviously, up to you to judge the best answer ;-)
But my perception is that my answer is the most precise, detailed and with relevant code samples :-)
If there is anything you're missing, or something is not working - let me know