# How to get data from 3 table into 1 list json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is my previous post.

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106799/how-to-get-data-from-3-table-into-1-list/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106799/how-to-get-data-from-3-table-into-1-list/).

It works fine.
But i expect returning value as:

```
[{ "id": "1f5a6c7c-6168-4ac8-73a5-08daf474a373", "name": "Bag A", "quantity": 10, "category": "Cat-A" }, { "id": "9b8eb0cc-0da4-4b6a-73a6-08daf474a373", "name": "Shirt A", "quantity": 10, "category": "Cat-B" }, { "id": "DB2EE420-A4E5-407A-5F96-08DAF4759F9C", "name": "Shoes A", "quantity": 10, "category": "Cat-C" } ]
```

I use .net core 6 MVC - code first. Please help me.

Comment: And here is your [other, other vague](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064854) post on the same topic

Comment: Hello sir. 1 post is closed. And this post is created by a request in my previous post.

Comment: This is not the proper way of creating question, please add your code snippet and write down in breif hat your expectations are.

Comment: As  all of your model has same property name so how could you display like that fashion?  Because, your each category have its own list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to return value without "bag", "shirts","shoes". Look like
> above:

Well, based on your question, you could achieve by introduing new model which would be containing all property that your "bag", "shirts","shoes" containing. Finally, you need to loop through the existing list item and bind those into new class/model. You can have a try in following way:

Create A new Model for generic List:

```
public class GenericClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** We will use this model to loop over our existing list thus we would bind them into this.

Base Model:

```
public class GenericClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
    public class Bags
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
    public class Shirts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
    public class Shoes
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Seed Data Into Model:

```
List<Bags> listBags = new List<Bags>();
            listBags.Add(new Bags() { Id = 101, Name = "Bag A", Quantity = 10, Category = "Cat-A" });
            listBags.Add(new Bags() { Id = 102, Name = "Bag B", Quantity = 15, Category = "Cat-A" });
            listBags.Add(new Bags() { Id = 103, Name = "Bag C", Quantity = 20, Category = "Cat-A" });

            List<Shirts> listShirts = new List<Shirts>();
            listShirts.Add(new Shirts() { Id = 101, Name = "Shirt A", Quantity = 10, Category = "Cat-B" });
            listShirts.Add(new Shirts() { Id = 102, Name = "Shirt B", Quantity = 15, Category = "Cat-B" });
            listShirts.Add(new Shirts() { Id = 103, Name = "Shirt C", Quantity = 20, Category = "Cat-B" });

            List<Shoes> listShoes = new List<Shoes>();
            listShoes.Add(new Shoes() { Id = 101, Name = "Shirt A", Quantity = 10, Category = "Cat-S" });
            listShoes.Add(new Shoes() { Id = 102, Name = "Shirt B", Quantity = 15, Category = "Cat-S" });
            listShoes.Add(new Shoes() { Id = 103, Name = "Shirt C", Quantity = 20, Category = "Cat-S" });
```

Build Custom List:

```
var genericClass = new List<GenericClass>();
           
            foreach (var item in listBags)
            {
                var bag = new GenericClass();
                bag.Id = item.Id;
                bag.Name = item.Name;
                bag.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                bag.Category = item.Category;
                genericClass.Add(bag);
            }

            foreach (var item in listShirts)
            {
                var shirt = new GenericClass();
                shirt.Id = item.Id;
                shirt.Name = item.Name;
                shirt.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                shirt.Category = item.Category;
                genericClass.Add(shirt);
            }

            foreach (var item in listShoes)
            {
                var shoes = new GenericClass();
                shoes.Id = item.Id;
                shoes.Name = item.Name;
                shoes.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                shoes.Category = item.Category;
                genericClass.Add(shoes);
            }
```

Complete Demo:

```
        [HttpGet("GetFrom3TablesWithSameKey")]
        public IActionResult GetFrom3TablesWithSameKey()
        {
            List<Bags> listBags = new List<Bags>();
            listBags.Add(new Bags() { Id = 101, Name = "Bag A", Quantity = 10, Category = "Cat-A" });
            listBags.Add(new Bags() { Id = 102, Name = "Bag B", Quantity = 15, Category = "Cat-A" });
            listBags.Add(new Bags() { Id = 103, Name = "Bag C", Quantity = 20, Category = "Cat-A" });

            List<Shirts> listShirts = new List<Shirts>();
            listShirts.Add(new Shirts() { Id = 101, Name = "Shirt A", Quantity = 10, Category = "Cat-B" });
            listShirts.Add(new Shirts() { Id = 102, Name = "Shirt B", Quantity = 15, Category = "Cat-B" });
            listShirts.Add(new Shirts() { Id = 103, Name = "Shirt C", Quantity = 20, Category = "Cat-B" });

            List<Shoes> listShoes = new List<Shoes>();
            listShoes.Add(new Shoes() { Id = 101, Name = "Shirt A", Quantity = 10, Category = "Cat-S" });
            listShoes.Add(new Shoes() { Id = 102, Name = "Shirt B", Quantity = 15, Category = "Cat-S" });
            listShoes.Add(new Shoes() { Id = 103, Name = "Shirt C", Quantity = 20, Category = "Cat-S" });


            var genericClass = new List<GenericClass>();
           
            foreach (var item in listBags)
            {
                var bag = new GenericClass();
                bag.Id = item.Id;
                bag.Name = item.Name;
                bag.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                bag.Category = item.Category;
                genericClass.Add(bag);
            }

            foreach (var item in listShirts)
            {
                var shirt = new GenericClass();
                shirt.Id = item.Id;
                shirt.Name = item.Name;
                shirt.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                shirt.Category = item.Category;
                genericClass.Add(shirt);
            }

            foreach (var item in listShoes)
            {
                var shoes = new GenericClass();
                shoes.Id = item.Id;
                shoes.Name = item.Name;
                shoes.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                shoes.Category = item.Category;
                genericClass.Add(shoes);
            }

            return Ok(genericClass);
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Note: If you still have any concern [please have a look on our official documnet here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections)

Comment: Alright, but while posting new question, share more details and your current code snippet where you are stuck in which would make contributor to visualize your issue accordingly.